# custom parameter to ag-grid valueFormatter function

Tags: ag-grid

Can i pass a custom parameter to ag-grid valueFormatter function
like
valueFormatter: percentageFormatter(params, '10')

If yes then what needs to be passed as first parameter to get the cell value?

Answer (score 12):

Function

```
percentageFormatter(percentage: number) {
  return (params) => {
    //your code goes here
    //**EDIT** this return will be what you will see in ag-grid
    return params.value * percentage;
  }
}
```

Then, in your column definition:

```
valueFormatter: percentageFormatter(10)
```

Comment: just for clarity, on your sample, it wouldn't be compiled.

Comment: @un.spike I am using this code in my project. I will try to write a plunker later today

Comment: This is excellent, using this method you can pass `this` to a formatter and have access to your Angular component!

Comment: Now all of a sudden my Angular app won't build, for lines like this: `valueFormatter: this.statusFormatter(this)` I am getting the error `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.`.  These lines were already marked in the VS code editor but it would build before I merged in another branch.  Can anyone offer an explanation?

Comment: Could you post statusFormatter function? @333Matt

Comment: Thanks for responding Rafael but I was also using `this` as the paramater name that the statusFormatter accepted.  Angular doesn't like when you use its' keywords as parameter names and changing that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

according the doc (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-setters/) 
`params` represents an interface : `ValueFormatterParams` which extends `BaseColDefParams` - which contain basics:

```
node: RowNode;
data: any;
colDef: ColDef;
column: Column;
api: GridApi;
columnApi: ColumnApi;
context: any;
```

and you can handle return `value` according to your conditions.

sample:

```
numberFormatter(params:ValueFormatterParams) {
if(...) -- heve you can check columns/values or any accessed parameters via api
    return Number(params.value).toLocaleString("es-ES", {minimumFractionDigits: 2});
else(...)
    return params.value;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I kept getting "NaN" on the cells and your sample code inspired me to check for type. Thank you!