# How does this big arrow notation work with ag-Grid value formatter?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I've created a service `GridFormatterService` in an angular project which contains static methods to use for value formatting within ag-Grid.

In some of the ag-Grids within the project, I need to pass a parameter `displayDateAndTime` (a boolean flag) from the column definition `valueFormatter` to my service to decide in what way the value will be formatted.

Doing this in the normal way, e.g -

```js
public columnDefs = {
    ... , valueFormatter: GridFormatterService.dateFormatter(params, displayDateAndTime), ...
}
```

Doesn't work. I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51108911/12677653) that solves this problem, so I implemented it in `dateFormatter` like so:

```js
public static dateFormatter(displayDateAndTime: boolean = false) {
    return (params: ValueFormatterParams) => { 
      if (params.value) { 
        if (!displayDateAndTime) { 
          return new Date(params.value).toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
        } else { 
          return moment(params.value).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

However, this implementation only works when the `displayDateAndTime` parameter is passed in. The parameter only needs to be passed in certain cases, and when you don't pass in a parameter (even if you set a default or allow it to be null), it breaks `dateFormatter` and causes the code, as a string, to be displayed in the ag-Grid. In this case, what I see displayed in the grid is `params => if (params.value)...`

My questions are twofold:

1. How does this big arrow notation allow the function to access `params` from ag-Grid, even though it's not passed in to the function?
2. How can I allow `dateFormatter` to have a default value for my flag without breaking the ag-Grid, and if I can't, is there another way of passing a parameter to `valueFormatter` that I'm missing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Tested it, and it works.

```
columnDefs = [
...
    {
      field: 'someField',
      valueFormatter: (params: ValueFormatterParams) =>
        GridFormatterService.dateFormatter(params, true),
    },
    {
      field: 'otherField',
      valueFormatter: (params: ValueFormatterParams) =>
        GridFormatterService.dateFormatter(params),
    },
...
]
```

here is the Service below.
Please note to tell typescript that a property may or may not exist, you have to use a question mark.

ie function(a: params, b?: boolean)

```
    class GridFormatterService {
...
      public static dateFormatter(
        params: ValueFormatterParams,
        displayDateAndTime?: boolean
      ) {
        if (params.value) {
          if (!displayDateAndTime) {
            return 'Format A';
          } else {
            return 'Format B';
          }
        }
      }
...
    }
```

Here is a link to a **working example**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-formatter?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Yeah this is how I ended up doing it, pity that I haven't been able to find an explanation of how that `(params) => ` function works though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Arrow function is essentially a more compact syntax to write functions, and it does not have it's own "this". 
Arrow functions "this" will point to the scope where it was declared.

Comment: ie you could have an object with a method to update its state.
if you declared this method as an arrow function, you could just pass the reference to this method anywhere, and it would still work. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: There is a good course on front-end masters that goes in-depth about functions by "Will Sentence", which can explain a lot better than me lol 
JavaScript: The Hard Parts, v2
https://frontendmasters.com/courses/javascript-hard-parts-v2/